# Stop Spam Registration on our Custom Registration Form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

We have a custom registration form on our wordpress website. we are using google recaptcha and input Human question field to stop spam registrations but still the spam registrations won't stop.

Could anyone suggest what exactly needs to be done?

The Registration form code is as follows.

The JS code has 2 functions one for Recaptcha and another for Validate the "Question field".

The register submit button is by default disabled and gets enabled only when the recaptcha call backs the function.

```js
function recaptchaCallback() {
  $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
}

function validateForm() {
  var a = document.forms["registerform"]["question"].value;
  var b = document.forms["registerform"]["user_login"].value;
  var c = document.forms["registerform"]["user_email"].value;
  if (a == null || a != "5") {
    alert("Bitte fülle alle Felder richtig aus");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<form name="registerform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label style="font-size:18px;">Register</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-md">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
    <input type="text" name="user_login" class=" form-control" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group input-group-md">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
    <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="Redirect_URL">
  <div class="input-group input-group-md">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></span>
    <input type="number" name="question" class="form-control" placeholder="2+3 = ?">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="captcha" class="form-group">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdOGg4TAAAAAJsTt_ZGoK67cyF277uIYwWRxJPW" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="pass-info" class="clearfix"></div>
    <button class="btn_full" id="submitBtn" disabled>Register</button>
</form>
```

The whole thing works fine, Recaptcha and Human question field. When we manually test registerform, we can't register without accepting the Recaptcha and inserting exactly the value to process the form.

But this is not preventing automatic spam bots which registers on our site.

Is there any other way through which these spam bots are registering ?

Also we disabled "MEMBERS CAN REGISTER" in the admin dashboard.

Are we doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance for the feedback and suggestions.

Comment: Probably a better & easier alternative is WordPress Zero Spam: https://wordpress.org/plugins/zero-spam/ Allows custom integration is highly effective in stopping spam & malicious IPs

Answer (score 1):

you need to do validate it in the backend, in the front end, validation can be bypassed.

store the ip address for each registration.dont allow registeration from the same ip within some period of time, but user can use some proxy tool which changes the ip address every second.

validate the email, foreach email send the validation email to registered email address, and if the user click on the activation click, activate the account, otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot the server-side part of recaptcha.
A robot should not be able to pass it multiple times, 
See this complete tutorial from google : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

You must configure a key on the server, as explained, that is secret, and which google will send to you if the captcha is valid.